# "Selecting" a monster that is "unaffected by card effects"; is it possible?

Tags: yu-gi-oh

So, if my opponent activates a card that makes me select one monster to destroy, I have 2 monster, 1 unaffected by card effects while the other can, can I select the unaffected?

I mean, as far as I know effects resolve against cards unaffected by card effects but as it says, it is unaffected, so, can I do that?

And would the same apply if I activate a card that makes me destroy one monster I own and I select the monster unaffected by effects?

Comment: ***Please***, include the specific card names so we can help you better.

Comment: Not a specific card, just a blue eyes targeted with The Ultimate Creature of Destruction.

Comment: Well... is it a specific Blue eyes? Only some are immune to destruction. Without mentioning specific cards it's hard to give a prop answer

Comment: @DarkCygnus It probably is Blue-eyes Chaos Max Dragon. That one cannot be targeted or destroyed by card effects.
So your answer does cover this scenario correctly.

Comment: @kyudosai that card was the one in my mind, but it never hurts to be completely sure :)

Comment: Any blue eyes, because The Ultimate Creature of destruction allows me to select one blue eyes and make it unaffected by other effects

Comment: Updated my answer in case you want to check it out :)

Answer (score 3):

**Update:** Seems that the card in question is [The Ultimate Creature of Destruction](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/The_Ultimate_Creature_of_Destruction), targeting *any* Blue-eyes monster. In that case, my previous answer holds.

---

> So, if my opponent activates a card that makes me select one monster to destroy, I have 2 monster, 1 unaffected by card effects while the other can, can I select the unaffected?

**Yes you can.**

You can select it and when the effect resolves it will not be destroyed, as The Ultimate Creature of Destruction made it unaffected bu such effect.

> And would the same apply if I activate a card that makes me destroy one monster I own and I select the monster unaffected by effects?

Again, **yes**.

If you monster is *unaffected* then the effect will resolve and such monster remain unaffected same as explained before...

However, let's imagine the card targets and the monster can't be targeted, then that would be something you *can't* do. However, this is not the case for The Ultimate Creature of Destruction, which "only" makes your monster unaffected by card effects (contrary to, say, making him un-targeteable).

Comment: Might be usefull to note that to destroy a monster and to send it to the graveyard are very different things.
So if a monster like 'blue-eyes chaos max dragon' is protected from destruction, it would not be protected from something like 'rivalry of warlords'.

Comment: @kyudosai true, but I feel a bit uncomfortable including such info without knowing the specific cards, as I would be deviating from the core of the question. Besides, I tend to write a lot on YGO answers :/ I am trying to condense my answers :)

Comment: @kyudosai updated my answer, as OP specified some of the cards used. Still, that trap card would make the dragon unaffected by card effects (for this turn), so even Rivalry of Warlords would be ineffective against it! :O